# phonegap gap:config-file to adjust mainpage.xaml

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, orientation, phonegap-build, system-tray

I am using phonegap build. I dont have a windows SDK around. I dont have mainpage.xaml around.

I want to hide the status bar in winphone8, as it is causing problems in my layout. I don't want android and ios to change. I've read adding this

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

to mainpage.xaml would do the trick.

Also, I'd want to lock the screen orientation. I read adding this

```
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
```

to mainpage.xaml would do the trick.

Can I do these things using a gap:config-file statement in config.xml ?